# Date formate conversion in Python

Tags: python, date, date-conversion

Hello I would like to know how i could convert the datetime object to a specific format.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime.today()
>>> d.ctime()
'Sat Jan 26 17:33:08 2013'
```

I would like the output or to get the current date in the format below

```
2013-01-26 17:33:08
```

Comment: Have you read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)? This is quite a trivial task...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`isoformat()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) gives you that:

```
d.isoformat(' ')
```

but might include microsends; you could use the [`.strftime()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) for some more control:

```
d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Output

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime.today()
>>> d.isoformat(' ')
'2013-01-26 13:12:08.628580'
>>> d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2013-01-26 13:12:08'
```

Comment: it gives me this '2013-01-26 17:33:08.272000' . i dont want the decimal part

Comment: @Coderx13: Yes, if your platform includes microseconds then `.isoformat()` adds those.